# Linq query from IEnumerable of integers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a logical problem within an `ASP.NET MVC` project. I'm developing a social media app that looks like Facebook. I got everything to work except one thing.

The application has a table called `Follow`, which contains `loggedInUser_ID` and `userToFollow_ID`.
I have a `IEnumerable` of integers that contains the list of `usersToFollow_ID` for the logged in user, the method looks like:

```
public IEnumerable<Post> postsForFlow(int userID, string userName)
{
    IEnumerable<int> userToFollowID = db.Follow.Where(a => 
        a.loggedInUser.Id == userID).Select(b => b.userToFollow.Id);

     return null;
}
```

How do I foreach over those integers to get all of the posts that the loggedInUser want to follow?

Can I resolve this with a Linq query?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this in memory, you should be doing this in the actual database query.

Comment: Do your models have navigation properties?  I suspect your `Select` clause should be using one or more of those properties to return the collection of `Post` objects.  Just guessing on the structure here, but something like: `.SelectMany(b => b.userToFollow.Posts)`

Comment: We can't know how you intend to turn a collection of user IDs into posts to follow.  How do you want to go about doing that?  Do you want to show all posts, recent posts, random selection of recent posts, posts other people have shown interest in, posts they haven't seen already, or what?  We can (potentially) help you figure out how to implement what you want, but we can't know *what* you want to implement.

Comment: @Servy I wanna show all of the posts that the loggedInUser are following. And I have all of those users in a IEnumerable.

Comment: @wallef Yes, you have all of the *users* that they're following, but how do you want to determine all of the *posts* that they're following?  Do you define the posts that they're following as all of the posts from all of the users that they're following?  Do they follow posts separately from users?  Do you want to determine some selection of of the posts of the users they're following as being "the posts that they're following", if so, how to do determine which posts they are?

Comment: @Servy I can get all of those Users ID. And all Posts have a connection with User_id

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work? This is assuming that `User` has a one to many relationship with `Posts`:

```
public IEnumerable<Post> PostsForFlow(int userId)
{
    var userIdsToFollow = db.Follow.Where(a =>
        a.loggedInUser.Id == userId).Select(b => b.userToFollow.Id);

    return db.Users
        .Where(u => userIdsToFollow.Contains(u.Id))
        .SelectMany(u => u.Posts);
}
```

**EDIT**

In order to test this, since I don't have your database, I just made some dummy classes to mock yours. If these are similar to what you have, then this should work.

The `User` table, which has an `Id` and a list of `Post`

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

The `Post` table, which just has a `Text` property (for testing)

```
public class Post
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

The `Follow` table, which has the loggedInUser and the userToFollow

```
public class Follow
{
    public User loggedInUser { get; set; }
    public User userToFollow { get; set; }
}
```

The 'db', which contains a list of `User` and a list of `Follow` (these are the tables)

```
public static class db
{
    public static List<Follow> Follow = new List<Follow>();
    public static List<User> Users = new List<User>();
}
```

Then I created a method to populate the database with 10 users. User Id '0' is the "logged in user", and users `1 - 9` are all being followed by user `0`, and they have 4 posts each

```
/// <summary>
/// This populates the Db with 10 users. All users
/// from 1 to 9 are being followed by user 0
/// </summary>
public static void PopulateDb()
{
    // Create the logged in user
    var loggedInUser = new User { Id = 0, Posts = new List<Post>() };
    db.Users.Add(loggedInUser);

    // Create 9 other users with 4 posts each
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var newUser = new User
        {
            Id = i,
            Posts =
                new List<Post>
                {
                    new Post {Text = "Post #" + i},
                    new Post {Text = "Post #" + (i * 10)},
                    new Post {Text = "Post #" + (i * 20)},
                    new Post {Text = "Post #" + (i * 30)}
                }
        };

        // Add the other user
        db.Users.Add(newUser);

        // Have the logged in user follow this new user
        db.Follow.Add(new Follow { loggedInUser = loggedInUser, 
            userToFollow = newUser });
    }
}
```

Then, to test it out, I just call the two methods:

```
public static void Main()
{
    PopulateDb();
    var postsForFlow = PostsForFlow(0);

    // Now postsForFlow has 36 entries - 4 for each
    // of the 9 users that user '0' is following
    Console.WriteLine(postsForFlow.Count());

    // Output: 36 (9 users * 4 posts each)

    // Now, to test it further, stop following all users who have even Ids
    // This will leave us with 5 users: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9
    foreach (var follow in db.Follow
        .Where(f => f.userToFollow.Id % 2 == 0)
        .ToList())
    {
        db.Follow.Remove(follow);
    }

    postsForFlow = PostsForFlow(0);
    Console.WriteLine(postsForFlow.Count());
    // Output: 20 (5 users * 4 posts each)
}
```

Comment: Hmm, when I try this I only get the posts for the first User the loggedInUser are following. I want to iterate through all of the Users posts that the loggedInUser are following. 
Thanks for your input

Comment: It's currently 5. But it may be more or few, depending if the loggedinuser follow/unfollow user

Comment: Well, I don't know your exact schema, but it works for me. Do all the ids in `userIdsToFollow` exist in `db.Users`, and do they all have at least one `Post`?

Comment: you are totally right! It works.
But the strange thing now, is that I can only get the property .Text to work, otherwise it gets an error. In my view: 
`@foreach (var item in Model.postsForFlow)
{
    <p>@item.Text </p>   
   
}` works. But if i want to display the user like 
`
@foreach (var item in Model.postsForFlow)
{
    <p>@item.Text says: @item.User </p>   
   
} 
`
I get a "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException".

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, you specified a method that returns a list of Posts, not users. Just change that part of the logic and the return value!

Comment: thank you so much for your help!! @Rufus L
I do want a list of Posts, but can't I get all of the Posts properties from this? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to get direct properties. If you want to get another table (like User) from the Post, you probably have to add an Include for those tables.

Comment: How would that look? Imagine that in the class User there is a property called Username that is a string.This is the last question. 
THANK YOU AGAIN!!

Comment: This is getting off topic from the original question. If this answer solved your initial problem, please mark it as answered and ask a new question!

Answer (score -1):

Just add a call to ToList():

```
public IEnumerable<Post> postsForFlow(int userID, string userName)
{
    var userToFollowID = db.Follow.Where(a => 
                  a.loggedInUser.Id == userID).Select(b => b.userToFollow.Id).ToList();
    userToFollowID.ForEach(user =>
          {
                Follow(user); // Use whatever logic you need for following.  "user" is the int you want
          });
    return null;
}
```

Comment: If he does want to `foreach` over the data, he can just use `foreach` and be done with it.  Of course, that *doesn't* actually get him the data that he wants (at least not alone).  There is also no reason to materialize the entire collection into a list here at all.  Finally, this work shouldn't be done in memory in the first place; the query should be done on the DB.